# How do you add multiple elements to Material-UI's AppBar component?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-design, material-ui

I want to have multiple FlatButton components in the Material-UI AppBar and preserve the style, so it looks like this (with multiple buttons).

[image]

However, when I try to add multiple FlatButton components, I get an error saying I need to wrap them in an enclosing tag. I've used both a span and a div with the same bad results.

[image]

Is there a way to either preserve the AppBar's style in the enclosing tag or a different way to add multiple elements to the AppBar itself to get the desired effect?

Answer (score 11):

The iconRightElement must be a single element, so you just need to wrap your buttons in a div like this:

```
render() {
  const buttonStyle = {
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    color: 'white'
  };

  const rightButtons = (
    <div>
      <FlatButton label="About" style={buttonStyle} />
      <FlatButton label="Home" style={buttonStyle} />
    </div>
  );

  return (
    <AppBar title="React seed" iconRightElement={rightButtons} />
  );
}
```

Comment: I think it should be `iconElementRight` now.

Answer (score 8):

I run into the same issue, and solved it using AppBar children. You might need to fix the styling of the buttons to make them look identical to the original ones

```
render() {
  var buttonStyle = {
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    color: 'white'
  };

  return (
    <AppBar title="React seed">
      <FlatButton label="About" style={buttonStyle} />
      <FlatButton label="Home" style={buttonStyle} />
    </AppBar>
  )}
```

Comment: If you do this your components will not be vertically centered. You can do this adding the flatbuttons to the iconRightElement prop

Comment: I believe that's iconElementRight: http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/app-bar

Answer (score 2):

You should use `getStyles` of `material-ui/AppBar/AppBar` and pass the style to child component (`FlatButton`, `IconMenu`, ...).
In order to use `getStyles`, you need to get `muiTheme` in context with declaration of `contextTypes`.

NOTE: If you want to use both FlatButton and IconMenu, you need to adjust FlatButton top position because of size deference between FlatButton and IconMenu. (`hasIconMenu == true` pattern)

```
import React             from 'react';
import AppBar            from 'material-ui/AppBar';
import { getStyles }     from 'material-ui/AppBar/AppBar';
import MenuItem          from 'material-ui/MenuItem';

class App extends React.Component {
  static get contextTypes() {
    return { muiTheme: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired };
  }
  render() {
    const styles = getStyles(this.props, this.context);
    const { button: { iconButtonSize }} = this.context.muiTheme;
    const { appBar } = this.context.muiTheme;
    const hasIconMenu = false;
    let iconMenu = null;
    if (hasIconMenu) {
      styles.flatButton.top = -styles.flatButton.marginTop;
      styles.flatButton.marginTop = 0;
      iconMenu = (
        <IconMenu
          iconStyle={styles.iconButtonIconStyle}
          iconButtonElement={<IconButton><MoreVertIcon /></IconButton>}
          targetOrigin={{horizontal: 'right', vertical: 'top'}}
          anchorOrigin={{horizontal: 'right', vertical: 'top'}}
        >
          <MenuItem primaryText="Refresh" />
          <MenuItem primaryText="Help" />
          <MenuItem primaryText="Sign out" />
        </IconMenu>
      );
    }
    const rightIcons = (
      <div>
        <FlatButton label="My Channels" style={styles.flatButton} />
        <FlatButton label="Favorite" style={styles.flatButton} />
        <FlatButton label="Login" style={styles.flatButton} />
        {iconMenu}
      </div>
    );

    return (
      <div>
        <AppBar
          title="Title"
          iconElementRight={rightIcons}
        />
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score -2):

You should do this

```
render() {
    const buttonStyle = {
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        color: 'white'
    };

    return (
        <AppBar title="React seed" iconRightElement={
            <FlatButton label="About" style={buttonStyle} />
            <FlatButton label="Home" style={buttonStyle} />
         } />
    )
}
```

Comment: this doesn't work, throws a parsing error and the  `AppBar` parameter should be `iconElementRight`